# vuejs & ukit html editor not displaying content

Tags: uikit, vue.js

I am using UIKIT & vuejs for front end, when i am trying to put content (retrieved runtime using vue-resource) inside textarea (htmleditor markdown component),

it doesn't show content inside htmleditor

but hard coding the text is working,it's not working when the on displaying dynamically retrieved  data

** html code : **

```
<textarea data-uk-htmleditor="{markdown:true,mode:'tab'}">{{hotel.description}}</textarea>
```

**  this is working if hard coded  property is used **
 
`<textarea data-uk-htmleditor="{markdown:true,mode:'tab'}">{{description}}</textarea>`
 
** Vue js code **

```
 export default {
  data () {
    return {
      is_edit:false,
      description:"This is hardcoded value",
      hotel: {}
    }
  },

  route: {
    data ({ to }) {
      return {
        hotel:this.details(to.params.slug) 
      }
    }
  },

  methods:{
     details (slug) {
        this.$http.get('/admin/hotels/' + slug)
                .success(function(hotel) {
                    this.hotel = hotel;
                }).error(function (error) {
                    alert("error")
                });
     }

  }
```

Comment: ```
 $.UIkit.htmleditor('#description', { /* options */ });

var editor = $('.CodeMirror')[0].CodeMirror;

editor.setValue(this.hotel.description);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do it like this; bind it the the form element

```
<textarea data-uk-htmleditor="{markdown:true,mode:'tab'}" v-model="hotel.description"></textarea>
```